# Common solutions for a set of inequalities

Tags: logic

First, please tolerate my stupidity. I'm a Software Engineering guy with minimal background in maths.

Suppose I have a set of first-order formulas over the theory of linear arithmetic: $\varphi_1, \varphi_2,\dots\varphi_n$. That means each $\varphi_i$ has the form: $$\varphi_i = (a_1x + b_1y < c_1) \wedge (a_2x + b_2y < c_2) \wedge \dots$$
Moreover these $\varphi_i$ are mutually exclusive:
$$\varphi_1 \wedge \varphi_2 \wedge \dots \wedge\varphi_n = \bot$$
I only care about the variable $x$, I would like to partition its domain in term of the formulas it can satisfy. What I need is a representative from each equivalent class of this partition. For example:

$x = x_1$ : only $\varphi_1$ is satisfiable
$x = x_2$ : $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ and $\varphi_3$ are satisfiable
$x = x_3$ : $\varphi_2$ and $\varphi_5$ are satisfiable
$\dots$

Note that I have [automatic tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability_modulo_theories) to find models of these formulas.

## **How I think I should do**:

I only need to find the models (each contains $x$) for all the pairs of formulas ($\varphi_i \wedge \varphi_j$). There are `n*(n-1)/2` such pairs, these `n*(n-1)/2` values of $x$ are the representative that I need to find.

This set of $x$ will contains solution for, e.g. $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ and $\varphi_3$, although I do not check for 3 formulas.

I tried to find a counterexample for this assumption on paper for a while, and I think it is correct. My questions are:

- Is my assumption truly correct? How I can prove or refute it?
- If yes, is it correct for other theory, apart from linear arithmetic?

Comment: The relevant keyword is "line arrangement". A line-sweep algorithm can compute what you want. See the book by Mark de Berg, Otfried Cheong, Marc van Kreveld, Mark Overmars, as one of the possible sources. (However, as the question is not about research-level math, I vote to close.)

Comment: @BorisBukh: Thank you for pointing me to the book. I also believe that I couldn't make a research level question with my math background. Could you give me a hint on my second question: in case the formulas are not in linear arithmetic, but e.g. bit vector, how I can solve it? Thank you.